# JQuery fadeIn() fires twice

Tags: jquery, fadein

I'm loading some html content via ajax on  click event. My code is-

```
$.ajax({
  url: somelink,
  async: true,
  beforeSend: function () {
      $("#myDiv").fadeOut("slow");
      $("#myDiv").empty();
  },
  success: function (data) {
      $('#myDiv').html(data);
      $("#myDiv").fadeIn("slow");
  },
  error: function (request, status, error) {
     alert("Error");
  },
  complete: function () {
  }
 });
```

Problem is #myDiv is fading in twice. What is the problem here?

Comment: Can you verify that the "success" callback itself is in fact only firing once? Have you tried to write a console.log in there to see if it's also getting fired twice? If it is, then your issue is outside the code you provided here.

Comment: whether the ajax is called twice

Comment: or show the div until the ajax is complete

Comment: Recommendations: remove `async: true` it's true by default, stop duplicating selectors, chain instead `$('#myDiv').html(data).fadeIn()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to be related to the html() call that actually shows the content really fast, then hides it again before the fadeIn kicks in. If the content is not updated fadeIn/out behaves as expected.

You can use a .hide() in the success function:

```
beforeSend: function () {
    $("#myDiv").fadeOut("slow").empty();
},
success: function (data) {
    $('#myDiv').hide().html("test!").fadeIn("slow");
},
```